# Using a trademarked word in the same business domain as the top-level domain (TLD) for typosquatting

Tags: european-union, trademark, domain-name

In this example, the names are fictional.

I have a fruit store called "aple" (with one p, which is commonly misspelled and is not a dictionary word). My real domain is "aple.store". "aple" is not trademarked for selling fruits.

Is it legal to register "apple.store" or "apple-store.com" for typosquatting even if "apple" is a registered trademark for selling fruits? The content of the page would be something like "did you mean aple.store?" with a link and an auto redirect to my domain. It would be even better (if allowed) to include words for SEO like "click here to get fresh apples".